# Undefined reference / multiple definition errors with GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, header-files

I'm a newcomer to C++. I'm having trouble building a simple multi-file project with `g++`. Here are my files:

**something.h**

```
class Something
{
public:
    void do_something() const;
} thing;
```

**something.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "something.h"

void Something::do_something() const
{
    std::cout << "Hello!" << std::endl;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "something.h"

int main()
{
    thing.do_something();
}
```

---

Here is what I tried:

- `g++ main.cpp` gives an error that `do_something` is an undefined reference, which makes sense because the compiler has no idea `something.cpp` has anything to do with `something.h`.
- `g++ main.cpp something.cpp`: there are 'multiple definitions' of `thing`, even though I clearly defined it only once.
- `g++ -c main.cpp something.cpp`: no errors! However, when I try running `g++ *.o` it gives me the same error as above, so I'm thinking this is a linker error.

Can anyone explain how to compile a multi-file project, and why my approach isn't working? I'm pretty confused right now because above is what most of the C++ examples on Stack Overflow look like.

---

Sidenotes:

- I *did* try the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix), but they didn't address linking issues with headers specifically.
- I'm not trying to redefine `thing` in `main`; if I wanted to do that, I would have typed up `Something thing`.

Comment: Do you know what 'thing' after the } does?

Comment: @CamelToe It creates a global variable called `thing`? At least that's what I was taught [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/structures/).

Comment: @Barmar I don't believe I'm redefining the global variable as in a `Something thing;` statement, I'm just trying to use it.

Comment: Since you have `#include "something.h"` in both `.cpp` files, that will try to define the variable in both of them. That's a redefinition.

Comment: Ok, do you know how the file is going to look like when everything is getting linked together? Replace every include with the source from the file and you'll get a hint

Comment: @Barmar Ah, so does that mean I have to add something like `#pragma once` to the header to prevent it from being re-pasted by the compiler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `g++ main.cpp` gives an error that `do_something` is an undefined reference, which makes sense because the compiler has no idea `something.cpp` [...]

... which contains the definition of the member function `do_something` exists. So you reference an undefined function.

> `g++ -c main.cpp something.cpp`: no errors! [...]

... since you're only compiling the files, not linking them together.

When you link them together, you end up with

> [...] 'multiple definitions' of `thing` [...]

which is exactly what you're doing:

```
class Something {
  // content
} thing;
```

is the same as

```
class Something {
 // content
};

Something thing;
```

And since `#include "something.h"` works by effectively copying the contents of the included file right into the including file, you end up with 2 files with a line

```
Something thing;
```

in each of them. And this is what the linker (called from the compiler frontend) is telling you: There are multiple definitions of the global variable `thing`.

To solve this: Don't put definitions for global variables into header files, only declarations:

```
extern Something thing;
```

And then add a definition in a single source file:

```
Something thing;
```

Or, better, try to avoid global variables.

---

One more thing: If you aren't doing it already, use include guards for your headers.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have added all files to the project.
Like if you are using IDE e.g, DEV C++ you have to add each .cpp or .h file to the project.